# Postgres 9.6 Physical and Logical replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, clustering

I am working with Postgres9.6 with a Master/Slave cluster replication using Streaming replication (physical).

I would like to add a new Slave server database but this database with logical replication.

I tried with some configurations but it was not possible  :(
https://github.com/guedim/postgres-streaming-replication

Here is the image of what is in my mind:

[image: Added picture inline]

Comment: At a minimum, I suggest adding your image directly into your question (pull down a local copy from GitHub, then follow the directions for inserting an image into your post).

Comment: "but it was not possible" why. That's just a fancy way of saying "it's broke."

Comment: Thanks @EvanCarroll.  Excuseme, I will try to publish my question following the directions for inserting images.  Thanks.

Comment: @MarioFernandoGuerreroDíaz already fixed it for you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having the same `wal_level` on all servers, as as it defines the amount of information you will have when WAL is *created* (on the primary, these files are then streamed to the standbys).

The available `wal_level` settings (with each setting writing more information to each WAL, as well as all that of lower levels) from low to high are:

- `minimal`
- `replica` (older values `archive` and `hot_standby` are mapped to this)
- `logical`

In this case I would set `wal_level = logical` for all. As WAL is only created in one place this won't hurt, and it has the added benefit of keeping working if you ever promote a standby to a master.

You mention `hot_standby` in the diagram, this has now been renamed `replica` (although both still work).

Other than that this topology should be fine, we use something like this - although you have logical replication from the standby, you'll need to move this to coming from the master. There was a rejected patch to allow this to come from a standby in PostgreSQL 10, hopefully this comes through in PostgreSQL 11.